# Smear/spread at the edges of a phone lens

Tags: optics, lens-design

My google-fu is failing me on this, because I don't know the term I'm looking for.

At the edges of a simple group shot of five or six people taken with a smartphone, there is a tendency for the faces of people at the edges to look 'flatter' and 'wider', as though they've been smeared outwards with a thumb on wet ink. It's not significantly out of focus, not blurry within the uninspiring parameters of a phone lens, just 'spread out' more than it ought to be.

Conversely, if I use my DSLR with an approximation of the same lens length - 18mm or so - I don't see this effect.

What is it called & what causes it on one lens/camera, yet not another?

I can't really provide an example, as a) I tend to only take these when I have to & also tend to throw them out as soon as I've sent them to interested parties & b) they would all be a line-up of faces who wouldn't necessarily want to be in this question. I can't blank the faces as that's the whole point of the question.

Comment: I do see [the same kind of thing with  a wide angle lens on my  DSLR (10mm since APS-C)](https://imgur.com/a/2Uv4gSj). See the shape of the white car. Yes, the picture is otherwise appalling :)

Comment: Oooh, Regent Street - Piccadilly Circus end? I used to work just a way up from there, Conduit Street :) Does seem to be similar, but I've never used anything that wide - 18 is the widest I've ever owned, which just accidentally approximately matches what my phone sees.

Comment: Yes, in November 2018.

Comment: An image of a regular geometric pattern (a grid, say) may help to visualize and identify the distortion.

Comment: Is this similar: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53623/why-the-faces-in-the-corner-tends-to-skew-a-bit-in-almost-all-smartphone-cameras

Comment: @Stan - yup, that's the one. Voted to close it myself, as a dupe of that & accepted it.